.NET build predicate with custom date format (not using client side). LinqKit
I don't know if this is possible.
I've been trying to implement a "global filter" that runs a "like" clause on the database engine and it varies a little bit depending on the column data type. To do so, I've been using LinqKit.
This is my current code. First of all, this is the global filter predicate builder:
/// <summary>
/// Gets a global filter predicate for the specified property name, filter value, and filter data type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity.</typeparam>
/// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property to filter on.</param>
/// <param name="filterValue">The value to filter with.</param>
/// <param name="filterDataType">The data type of the filter (text, numeric, date, boolean).</param>
/// <returns>
/// An expression representing the filter predicate for the specified property and filter value.
/// Returns null if the data type is not supported.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown when the filterDataType is not supported.</exception>
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>>? GetGlobalFilterPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string filterValue, string filterDataType) {
    Expression<Func<T, bool>>? predicate = null; // Initialize the predicate as null
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"); // Create an expression parameter to represent the generic entity T
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName); // Get the specific property of the entity using the provided property name
    if(filterDataType == "text" || filterDataType == "numeric" || filterDataType == "date") { // Check the filter data type, if it's text, numeric, or date, call method to create a filter predicate
        predicate = CreateTextFilterPredicate<T>(property, filterValue, "contains");
    } else if (filterDataType != "boolean") { // If the filter data type is not text, numeric, date or boolean, throw an exception
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid filterDataType value", nameof(filterDataType));
    }
    return predicate; // Return the predicate (may be null if the data type is not supported)
}

As you can see from the above code, if my filterDataType is date (the one I'm having issues with), it will call the CreateTextFilterPredicate. The function called is as follows:
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateTextFilterPredicate<T>(MemberExpression property, string filterValue, string matchMode = "contains") {
    #region PREPARE THE toStringMethod
    Expression toStringMethod; // Prepare the method to convert the property to a string if necessary
    bool isStringProperty = property.Type == typeof(string) || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type) == typeof(string); // Check if the property type is a string or nullable string
    bool isDateTimeProperty = property.Type == typeof(DateTime) || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type) == typeof(DateTime); // Check if the property type is DateTime or nullable DateTime
    if(isStringProperty) { // If the property is a string (or nullable string)
        toStringMethod = property; // Get the property as is, its already a string
    } else if(isDateTimeProperty) { // If the property is DateTime (or nullable DateTime)
        toStringMethod = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", null); // We need to cast ToString
    } else { // The property is not a string
        toStringMethod = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", null); // We need to cast ToString
    }
    #endregion
    MethodCallExpression toUpperMethod = Expression.Call(toStringMethod, "ToUpper", null); // Convert property string to uppercase (for case insensitive search)
    filterValue = filterValue.ToUpper(); // Convert filter value to uppercase (for case insensitive search)
    dynamic matchModeCheck = matchMode switch { // Create the predicate based on the match mode
        "startsWith" => Expression.Call(toUpperMethod, "StartsWith", null, Expression.Constant(filterValue)),
        "contains" => Expression.Call(toUpperMethod, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(filterValue)),
        "notContains" => Expression.Not(Expression.Call(toUpperMethod, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(filterValue))),
        "endsWith" => Expression.Call(toUpperMethod, "EndsWith", null, Expression.Constant(filterValue)),
        "equals" => Expression.Equal(toUpperMethod, Expression.Constant(filterValue)),
        "notEquals" => Expression.NotEqual(toUpperMethod, Expression.Constant(filterValue)),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Invalid filtering option value for text predicate", nameof(matchMode)),
    };
    #region PREPARE THE predicateBody
    dynamic predicateBody; // Prepare the predicate body
    if(isStringProperty) { // If filterDataType is text
        BinaryExpression nullCheck = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(null)); // Prepare binary expression to check for null values
        predicateBody = Expression.AndAlso(nullCheck, matchModeCheck); // Combine null check and string matching conditions using AndAlso
    } else {// If filterDataType is not text
        predicateBody = matchModeCheck; // Just use the matching conditions
    }
    #endregion
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicateBody, property.Expression as ParameterExpression); // Create and return the lambda expression
}

My current code works if I want to search a string in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. What I'm stuck with is trying to specify a custom date conversion that takes into account the culture. For example, I would like to specify that the date format for comparison should be dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss in the en-us culture.
I've tried, for example, this at the beginning in the case of if(isDateTimeProperty) (still not implementing the culture, but just to test the date conversion):
var dateTimeFormat = Expression.Constant("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Specify the desired date format
toStringMethod = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", null, dateTimeFormat);

However if gives me the following error:

"An unexpected error occurred: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .OrderBy(t => t.LocationDesignation)\r\n    .Where(t => t.LocationDesignation != null && t.LocationDesignation.ToUpper().Contains("0") || t.DateCreated.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToUpper().Contains("0"))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ToString' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.\r\nTranslation of method 'System.DateTime.ToString' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Is there a way to achieve what I want without doing a client side evaluation?
Example of the use case
Its a table were the user in the frontend the user sees the date with a mask. The global filter should search in the date column taking into account that date mask.

Thanks in advance!

Dates don't have formats, they're binary values. Both .NET's DateTime and the date types in all databases (except SQLite) are binary values. In the few databases where you have to store dates as strings the format is always ISO8901. Localized formats like dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss can't be sorted properly and thus can't be indexed effectively or even used in range queries.

In short, there's no need for the question's code. Either the field is a date type in which case you can compare it to a DateTime or DateOnly, or it's a text type containing ISO8601 values in which case you compare it with another ISO8601 string. If you want to use a localized string, it's a bug

You may want to spend some time thinking about which use cases you actually want to support. It's hard for me to imagine a scenario where I want to find all items whose date, when rendered a specific way, includes a specific string. Typically I'm going to want to pick a date range and find items that fall within that range.

@PanagiotisKanavos currently as I stated, I was able to cast to string the datetime. The thing is that the format it is using is dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, and I would like to specify other formats.

@AlexIbrahimOjea there are no formats. What you ask is completely wrong, guaranteed to return bad results and, given the generated expressions, the slowest possible query even if it run. Trying to use a localized string to compare with a binary date value, like filterDataType == "date" is trying to do, is completely wrong

@AlexIbrahimOjea if the database has a table where dates are stored as strings, it's a bug. Fix the bug instead of covering it up.

@PanagiotisKanavos dates are stored as datetime in the database. Look at my post. I've added an example use case at the end.

The image you posted shows that you still misunderstand what dates are. How the binary dates are displayed is up to the client application. That doesn't mean those binary dates have some specific format. The very fact the error contains t.DateCreated.ToString means the DateCreated field is a proper date type. Modify your query to compare with a DateTime value, not a string.

The only thing you have to do is to parse the filter strings into DateTime values or use a DatePicker control which gives you DateTime values directly. Use that DateTime value in your query

If you want to create a global query filter to only show entities in the last year, modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.DateCreated> DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)); is enough

And if you want to create a function that applies a date filter to types that implement some eg IDated interface with a DateTime DateCreated property, public static IQueryable<T> After<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,DateTime date) where T:IDated =>query.Where(x=>x.DateCreated>date).
